# 2-disk RAID array missing one disk. fdisk sees them both. Missing disk is "non-fresh". What to do?

Tags: 12.04, raid, mdadm

I have two physical 500 GB hard disks in my Ubuntu **12.04.4** PC and they are supposed to be in a 2-disk RAID array. However, **mdadm -D /dev/md0** is reporting that **/dev/sda seems to be inoperative**, even after a reboot:

```
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Sat Oct 12 20:01:52 2013
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 471531328 (449.69 GiB 482.85 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 471531328 (449.69 GiB 482.85 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 1
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Tue Jun 24 22:57:41 2014
          State : clean, degraded 
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           Name : xxxxx:0  (local to host xxxxx)
           UUID : d87b72eb:17425250:dfbf806f:60eba0fc
         Events : 4482651

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       0        0        0      removed
       1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
```

Similarly for md1 and sda5/sdb5. **fdisk** sees both sda and sdb. I see this in **/proc/mdstat**:

```
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md1 : active raid1 sdb5[1]
      16712576 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [_U]

md0 : active raid1 sdb1[1]
      471531328 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [_U]

unused devices: <none>
```

**dmesg** shows this:

```
[    2.187963] md: linear personality registered for level -1
[    2.189389] md: multipath personality registered for level -4
[    2.190202] md: raid0 personality registered for level 0
[    2.191153] md: raid1 personality registered for level 1
[    2.329273] md: bind<sda1>
[    2.330746] md: bind<sda5>
[    2.342623] md: bind<sdb1>
[    2.343018] md: kicking non-fresh sda1 from array!
[    2.343022] md: unbind<sda1>
[    2.435343] md: raid6 personality registered for level 6
[    2.435346] md: raid5 personality registered for level 5
[    2.435348] md: raid4 personality registered for level 4
[    2.437993] md: raid10 personality registered for level 10
[    2.439651] md: export_rdev(sda1)
[    2.440324] md/raid1:md0: active with 1 out of 2 mirrors
[    2.440341] md0: detected capacity change from 0 to 482848079872
[    2.460418]  md0: unknown partition table
[    2.481119] md: bind<sdb5>
[    2.483049] md: kicking non-fresh sda5 from array!
[    2.483066] md: unbind<sda5>
[    2.486916] md: export_rdev(sda5)
[    2.487564] md/raid1:md1: active with 1 out of 2 mirrors
[    2.487578] md1: detected capacity change from 0 to 17113677824
[    2.495906]  md1: unknown partition table
```

**What is this "non-fresh sda1" message?**

I have seen **[this message](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/md-kicking-non-fresh-sda6-from-array-416853/) on linuxquestions.org**. **Should I do what it says**, i.e.:

```
/sbin/mdadm /dev/md0 --fail /dev/sda1 --remove /dev/sda1
/sbin/mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/sda1

/sbin/mdadm /dev/md1 --fail /dev/sda5 --remove /dev/sda5
/sbin/mdadm /dev/md1 --add /dev/sda5
```

I assume that this would not affect **sdb** in any way. Thanks.

Comment: did you have an unclean shutdown that may have caused this issue? What were the circumstances in which the problem occurred?

Comment: There was probably an unclean shutdown indeed. It would have been a power failure.

Comment: if you've had an unclean shutdown, this can happen. Try this link and replace your sda5 with sda1: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/md-kicking-non-fresh-sda6-from-array-416853/

Comment: The --remove commands failed because the devices were not found, but the --add commands apparently succeeded. mdadm now says "State : clean, degraded, recovering" and "spare rebuilding" for md0, and "State : clean, degraded, resyncing (DELAYED)" and "spare rebuilding" for md1. I guess the "delayed" means sda5 will be recovered when sda1 is done. Thanks.

Comment: It turns out that root had been getting mail for some time from "mdadm monitoring" about having detected a "DegradedArray event". I was not getting that mail in my regular account, because I had not redirected root's mail to it. I fixed that using /etc/aliases and the newaliases command.

Answer (score 0):

Providing this answer in the proper format rather than just a [link](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/md-kicking-non-fresh-sda6-from-array-416853/) from a comment.

"This can happen after an unclean shutdown (like a power fail). Usually removing and re-adding the problem devices will correct the situation."

Refer to your specific drive configuration and mdadm version specific documentation for how to do this.

Another alternative is using the Gnome Disks utility. Select 'Raid Disks' (Ctrl+R) and then select + and then your missing raid drive. After confirming that all data will be wiped from the drive being added, the newly re-added drive should go to 'Recovering'. Closing the dialog will take you back to the main Disks screen. It should show a progress bar with Recovering: x.x% and the estimated time to complete the syncing.

[image]